# Select IDs which belongs ONLY to the list passed as parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's start from data:

```
DECLARE @Avengers TABLE ([Hero] varchar(32), [Preference] varchar(32));

INSERT INTO @Avengers VALUES
('Captain_America','gingers'),('Captain_America','blondes'),
('Captain_America','brunettes'),('Hulk','gingers'),('Hulk','blondes'),
('Hawkeye','gingers'),('Hawkeye','brunettes'),('Iron_Man','blondes'),
('Iron_Man','brunettes'),('Thor','gingers'),('Nick_Fury','blondes');
```

Now I would like to pass a `@Preferences` as a list of `[Preference]` (either comma separated or single column table parameter) without knowing how many parameters I am going to get and based on this to select `[Hero]` who prefers **exactly** these `@Preferences` as provided in parameter (list), by that I mean if I am after `'blondes'` and `'gingers'` then I am after `'Hulk'` **only**
(**NOT** 'Captain_America' who prefers  'blondes', 'gingers' and 'brunettes').

I would like to get something like:

```
SELECT [Hero]
FROM @Avengers
WHERE *IS_ASSIGNED_ONLY_TO_THE_LIST*([Preference]) = @Preference
```

Comment: if you use a table variable then you can use it within an IN clause

Comment: If I use IN clause then I will get values which hits whatever is inside the IN(), so in that case I will get both 'Captain_America' and 'Hulk' for IN ('blondes', 'gingers'). What I want is 'Hulk' only as his assigned to exactly and only the same parameters as they are in IN() clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I overcomplicated my code, but it works.

```
SELECT a.Hero, COUNT(*), MIN(p.N)
FROM @Avengers a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() N
            FROM @Preferences) p
    ON a.Preference = p.Preference
GROUP BY a.Hero
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(p.N)
AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(p.Preference)
;
```

I'm using `@Preferences` as a table.